# How do we test asynchronous middleware with asynchronous side effects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So my middleware is somewhat like this:

```js
const mw = async (req, res, next) => {
    await someAsyncWork();
    res.on("finish", async () => {
        await someAsyncCleanup();
    });
    next();
}
```

Here testing `someAsyncWork()` is quite easy as this is done in a sequential manner. But as you can see, I am listening to the `finish` event with an async listener. Testing whether the cleanup was done properly is a bit problematic. Are this kind of scenarios not testable or is there any better practice to avoid these scenarios. Or as the last resort, should someone use stubs as a replacement just to check if the listener is invoked and test the `someAsyncCleanup` separately?

Comment: why don't you pass something that looks like an event emitter and you can control it.

Comment: Right I am already doing something like that. `res` object is like this ```res = { ..., on: (event, listener) => eventListeners[event] = listener```. I am invoking `eventListener.finish()` on the `next` function which is passed to the middleware. But `eventListener.finish()` is an async function here.

Comment: so make your test async. javascript allows you to do a lot of things.

Comment: It's already async and I am awaiting on the middleware to finish. `await mw(req, res, () => eventListener.finish())`

Comment: If I want to await on the invocation I have to make the `next` function async. Which puts me back to where I started